# Slow SQL query with GROUP BY optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, database-performance

I have a MySQL DB. Acquired data are stored in `raw_data_headers`, `raw_data_rows` and `raw_data_row_details` table.

`raw_data_row_details` has a foreign key that reference `raw_data_rows.ID`, the same for `raw_data_rows` and `raw_data_headers`.

In `raw_data_headers` are stored data headers, in `raw_data_rows` are stored every stage of acquisition program and in `raw_data_row_details` are stored details for each stage of acquisition program.

This is the query:

```
SELECT
    q1.ProcessTypeID,
    q1.TestTypeID,
    q1.ComponentID,
    q1.TestResultID,
    COUNT(*) AS Counter
FROM (
    SELECT
        raw_data_headers.batch_id AS BatchID,
        raw_data_test_outputs.test_output_type_id AS TestOutputTypeID,
        raw_data_test_types.process_type_id AS ProcessTypeID,
        raw_data_test_types.ID AS TestTypeID,
        raw_data_row_details.component_id AS ComponentID,
        raw_data_test_results.ID AS TestResultID
    FROM raw_data_row_details
    INNER JOIN raw_data_rows ON raw_data_rows.ID = raw_data_row_details.row_id
    INNER JOIN raw_data_headers ON raw_data_headers.ID = raw_data_rows.header_id
    INNER JOIN raw_data_test_results ON raw_data_test_results.ID = raw_data_row_details.Value
    INNER JOIN raw_data_test_outputs ON raw_data_test_outputs.ID = raw_data_row_details.test_output_id
    INNER JOIN raw_data_test_types ON raw_data_test_types.ID = raw_data_test_outputs.test_type_id
    HAVING TestOutputTypeID = 2 AND BatchID = 1
) AS q1
GROUP BY q1.ProcessTypeID, q1.TestTypeID, q1.ComponentID, q1.TestResultID
```

`raw_data_headers` has 989'180 entries, `row_data_rows` has 2'967'540 entries and `raw_data_row_details` has 13'848'520 entries.

The subquery `q1` take about 3 minutes, but final query takes about 25 minutes. I think that the point is in the `GROUP BY`.
How can I improve performance?

**EDIT 1:**

```
SELECT
    gnuhmi.raw_data_test_types.process_type_id AS ProcessTypeID,
    gnuhmi.raw_data_test_types.ID AS TestTypeID,
    gnuhmi.raw_data_row_details.component_id AS ComponentID,
    gnuhmi.raw_data_test_results.ID AS TestResultID,
    COUNT(*) AS Counter
FROM gnuhmi.raw_data_row_details
INNER JOIN gnuhmi.raw_data_rows ON gnuhmi.raw_data_rows.ID = gnuhmi.raw_data_row_details.row_id
INNER JOIN gnuhmi.raw_data_headers ON gnuhmi.raw_data_headers.ID = gnuhmi.raw_data_rows.header_id
INNER JOIN gnuhmi.raw_data_test_results ON gnuhmi.raw_data_test_results.ID = gnuhmi.raw_data_row_details.Value
INNER JOIN gnuhmi.raw_data_test_outputs ON gnuhmi.raw_data_test_outputs.ID = gnuhmi.raw_data_row_details.test_output_id
INNER JOIN gnuhmi.raw_data_test_types ON gnuhmi.raw_data_test_types.ID = gnuhmi.raw_data_test_outputs.test_type_id
WHERE gnuhmi.raw_data_test_outputs.test_output_type_id = 2 AND gnuhmi.raw_data_headers.batch_id = 1
GROUP BY
    gnuhmi.raw_data_test_results.ID,
    gnuhmi.raw_data_row_details.component_id,
    gnuhmi.raw_data_test_types.ID,
    gnuhmi.raw_data_test_types.process_type_id
```

This is the new query, without subquery and `WHERE`. This increased performance (thanks @Yogesh Sharma).

this is `raw_data_headers` structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `raw_data_headers` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Univocal record key',
  `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product numeric ID',
  `Datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Univocal record creation date',
  `batch_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Univocal batch key',
  `RecipeName` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Used recipe name',
  `RecipeVersion` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Used recipe version',
  `process_result_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Process result key',
  `invalidated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'invalidation after counters reset',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_raw_data_headers_batches_ID` (`batch_id`),
  KEY `FK_raw_data_headers_process_re` (`process_result_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_raw_data_headers_batches_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`batch_id`) REFERENCES `batches` (`ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_raw_data_headers_process_re` FOREIGN KEY (`process_result_id`) REFERENCES `process_result` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores raw data headers'
```

This the `raw_dato_rows`:

```
CREATE TABLE `raw_data_rows` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Univocal record key',
  `Datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Univocal record creation date',
  `header_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Univocal raw data header key',
  `process_type_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Univocal process type key',
  `process_result_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Univocal process result key',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_raw_data_rows_header_id` (`header_id`),
  KEY `FK_raw_data_rows_process_resu2` (`process_result_id`),
  KEY `FK_raw_data_rows_process_resul` (`process_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_raw_data_rows_header_id` FOREIGN KEY (`header_id`) REFERENCES `raw_data_headers` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_raw_data_rows_process_resu2` FOREIGN KEY (`process_result_id`) REFERENCES `process_result` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_raw_data_rows_process_resul` FOREIGN KEY (`process_type_id`) REFERENCES `process_types` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2967541 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores row data rows'
```

and finally this is the `raw_data_row_details` one:

```
CREATE TABLE `raw_data_row_details` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Univocal row detail  key',
  `row_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Univocal row key',
  `test_output_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Univocal test output key',
  `component_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The component that take the measurement',
  `Value` double NOT NULL COMMENT 'Output value',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_raw_data_row_details_row_id` (`row_id`),
  KEY `FK_raw_data_rows_raw_data_test_outputs_ID` (`test_output_id`),
  KEY `raw_data_row_details_components_FK` (`component_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_raw_data_row_details_row_id` FOREIGN KEY (`row_id`) REFERENCES `raw_data_rows` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_raw_data_rows_raw_data_test_outputs_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`test_output_id`) REFERENCES `raw_data_test_outputs` (`ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `raw_data_row_details_components_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`component_id`) REFERENCES `components` (`ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13848521 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores raw data rows details'
```

Comment: update your question and add  your tables schema for see  which indexes  you are have

Comment: What is the size of your result (I mean, after waiting 25 minutes, how many records you get as output)?

Comment: @scaisEdge I updated the question

Comment: @FDavidov after grouping about 17 records

Comment: And before grouping? I mean, your query may (potentially) generate a **HUGE** result...

Comment: @FDavidov in this case all the `raw_data_row_details` entries, so 13'848'520 results

Comment: OK, in that case, both times are suspicious. 3 minutes for the sub-query indicates that you either have issues with indices or platform resources. Outer query points to platform resources (no indices involved). I would suggest resources of your computer while executing the entire query.

Comment: Without inner query, using `WHERE` it takes about 7 minutes (all foreign keys and indices are indexed).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `subquery`, just use `where` clause with `group by` :

```
SELECT  raw_data_test_types.process_type_id AS ProcessTypeID,
        raw_data_test_types.ID AS TestTypeID,
        raw_data_row_details.component_id AS ComponentID,
        raw_data_test_results.ID AS TestResultID, COUNT(*) AS Counter
FROM raw_data_row_details INNER JOIN 
     raw_data_rows 
     ON raw_data_rows.ID = raw_data_row_details.row_id INNER JOIN 
     raw_data_headers 
     ON raw_data_headers.ID = raw_data_rows.header_id INNER JOIN 
     raw_data_test_results 
     ON raw_data_test_results.ID = raw_data_row_details.Value INNER JOIN 
     raw_data_test_outputs 
     ON raw_data_test_outputs.ID = raw_data_row_details.test_output_id INNER JOIN 
     raw_data_test_types 
     ON raw_data_test_types.ID = raw_data_test_outputs.test_type_id
WHERE raw_data_headers.batch_id = 1 AND raw_data_test_outputs.test_output_type = 2
GROUP BY raw_data_test_types.process_type_id, raw_data_test_types.ID,
         raw_data_row_details.component_id, raw_data_test_results.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes. `TestOutputTypeID` and `BatchID` need to be covered and probably are not.

To see what's currently going on, use `EXPLAIN` in the MySQL console. You will probably see an indication that a full table scan is happening i.e. the join type is marked as `ALL`.

It's often the case that the query optimiser will use the same execution plan for different queries e.g. by expanding the subquery as if you hadn't used it. Only `EXPLAIN` will show you what's what.

Here's the docs on how to interpret the `EXPLAIN` output: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html

Comment: Mark, indices could explain the 3-minutes of the inner select, but not the 22 minutes of the outer (which is, in fact, performing the `GROUP BY` only. As I wrote to the PO, it smells as a platform resources issue.

Comment: @FDavidov Without inner query, using `WHERE` it takes about 7 minutes (all foreign keys and indices are indexed). Is it possible to increase performance?

Comment: @NickF_93, 7 minutes is an eternity. I strongly suggest you check the platform's resources while executing the query. Note that this check must be carried out at the computer where the DB is actually running, not the computer you are working from (e.g. where you Management Studio is running), unless it is the same computer of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
HAVING TestOutputTypeID = 2 AND BatchID = 1
```

Change that from `HAVING` to `WHERE`, and have indexes in each of those columns.

Also have these indexes:

```
raw_data_row_details:  (row_id)
raw_data_rows:         (header_id)
raw_data_row_details:  (test_output_id)
raw_data_test_outputs: (test_type_id)
```

Get rid of `raw_data_` from the table names; it just clutters the queries.

If those do not help enough, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.